# What purpose does nody-gyp rebuild during npm install of fsevents serve?

Tags: node.js, create-react-app, node-gyp, fsevents

Well I am currently in the process of streamlining the build system, to make everything work and manage we create a temporary (`node12-alpine` based) docker that builds a project made with `create-react-app`.

The docker has as entrypoint: `ENTRYPOINT npm ci --only=production && npm run build`

This works, except an error is returned:

```
> fsevents@1.2.11 install /javascript/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:179:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:322:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-76-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /javascript/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Now I understand why python fails - there's no python installed on alpine linux by default. However why would I need this to run? - The project seems to work fine without it?

What purpose does the `node-gyp rebuild`/`fsevents` serve? Should I actually fix this?

---

Checking for use of fsevents shows:

```
├─┬ @babel/cli@7.8.3
│ └─┬ chokidar@2.1.8
│   └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fsevents@1.2.11 
└─┬ react-scripts@3.3.0
  ├─┬ babel-jest@24.9.0
  │ └─┬ @jest/transform@24.9.0
  │   └─┬ jest-haste-map@24.9.0
  │     └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fsevents@1.2.11 
  └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fsevents@2.1.2
```

Comment: Probably some kind of filesystem-watching reload for development. Use `npm ls fsevents` to find out what’s using it – maybe you don’t even need the dependent for production.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Can you add some update on how you have solved it?